# Ajax call is successfull but $_POST['value'] is empty

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

**ISSUE SOLVED**

> The issues seemed to be browser related. Tried with a different system
>   and it works fine.

I am coding a live search to show the details of users from database using ajax and php. The input from the form fields are getting passed to the ajax file properly. I checked with console.log() and it is printing properly. After that, the Ajax call takes place without any errors. But when trying to echo the $_POST['search'], it is printing empty space.

**searchform.php**

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search" class="search"/>
<div class="search-result"></div>
```

**search.js**

```
    $(function(){
    $('.search').keyup(function(){
        var search = $(this).val();
        //console.log(search);
        $.ajax({
            url:'search.php',
            data:{search:search,},
            type:'POST',
            success:function(data){
                console.log(data);
                $('.search-result').html(data);
            },
            error:function(){
                console.log("error");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**search.php**

```
 <?php

include('core/init.php');
echo $_POST['search'];

?>
```

**EDITED**

I figured out the issue, but no idea about the cause and no solution found. It is basically that the `include('core/init.php');` is not getting included. I tried `var_dump(include('core/init.php'));` and it is returning bool(false).The path is correct. Is there something that needs to be done when file with `includes` is called using ajax.?

Comment: change this `data:{search:search,}` to this `data:{search:search}`. before you call ajax, your console.log show the value? and try to change your echo become this `echo json_encode($_POST['search'])`; for more complex you can `inspect element` goingto `network` tab and `open in new tab` your `search.php` file. it is show your expected value?

Comment: yes. the `console.log(search)` shows the value correctly

Comment: Check the network tab of your browser's debugger tools and at the exact request; is it sent as JSON encoded data, or as form-encoded data?

Comment: how about my other tips checking?

Comment: I didn't change a thing from your code and it worked fine. What is in **init.php**? Maybe something in there is terminating code execution before it gets to echoing the '$_POST['search']`.

Comment: i tried the`echo json_encode($_POST['search'])` and it worked fine. After that I commented it and tried  `echo $_POST['search']` and this time it also worked fine. I have no idea how that worked.

Comment: @CliffRono init.php file is not having any problem, it just connects the database and some includes files.

Comment: maybe your js not updated, you can ctrl + f5 (hard refresh) for make sure your js is updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **First,** you change this `data:{search:search,}` to this
>   `data:{search:search}`
>
> **Second**, try to change your `echo` in your `search.php` become this
>   `echo json_encode($_POST['search']);`
>
> **For more complex checking**, you can `inspect element` (press F12 from your browser), go to `network`
>   tab and open in new tab your `search.php` file. It is show your expected
>   value?
>
> If `search.php` shown the expected value, try to **hard refresh** your
>   browser in windows (ctrl + F5) to try updated your js

Comment: Since ECMAScript 5 it's allowed to have trailing commas in objects.

Comment: Can you explain all that further? Why should **encoding** the value that seems to be empty solve the problem? Shouldn't one **decode** posted data in the backend?

Comment: I figured out the issue, but no idea about the cause and no solution found. It is basically that the `include('core/init.php');` is not getting included. I tried `var_dump(include('core/init.php'));` and it is returning `bool(false)`.The path is correct. Is there something that need to be done when called using ajax.?

Answer (score 1):

Remove comma in data:{search:search,}
I recommend to use jquery $ prefix to vars to don't get confused, following code works.
HTML side

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready( function() {


            $('#search-btn').on('click', function() {

                $search = $('#search-txt').val();
                console.log($search);

                $.ajax({
                    url:'search.php',
                    data:{search: $search},
                    type:'POST',
                    success:function(data){

                        console.log(data);
                        $('#what-you-searched').html(data);
                    },
                    error:function(){
                        console.log("Error");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="search-txt" type="text">
    <input id="search-btn" type="button" value="search">

    <p>You searched</p><p id="what-you-searched"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

---

PHP side

```
<?php
    echo $_POST['search'];
?>
```

---

Here is what my code does:

$(document).ready(fuc)
/* code will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to be executed*/

$().on('click', func)
/* listener: triggered when a user click on a DOM object, in this case the search input tag (which is a button)*/

When user click on "Submit" button $search will be filled up with #search-txt value and tha Ajax method is called (passing $search as search to the backend).
My PHP backend simply echo the searched content.
JS on Success fills #what-you-searched with returned value

Comment: Since ECMAScript 5 it's allowed to have trailing commas in objects.

Comment: Please add some more explanation to your answer such that the OP can learn from it - what have you changed and why?

Comment: Edited adding explanation.

Answer (score -2):

There is no extra key/value pair in this object `data:{search:search,}` so do not need to add "," at the end. You should just use `data:{search:search}`.

Hope it will work.

Comment: That trailing comma is not a problem.

Comment: In the JS object notation, it is an issue i think. But thanks for the tip.

Comment: Not since ES5: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Trailing_commas

Comment: Please explain why the trailing comma would have been a problem. If that code were syntactically invalid, some error would have been thrown